# The unit circle is homotopic to a point in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Definition:** Let $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[0,1]\to G$ two rectifiable curves and $G\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ an open connected set. We say $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are homotopic in $G$ if there exists $\Gamma:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to G$ continuous such that:
>
> \begin{cases} 
>       \Gamma(s,0)=\gamma_0(s), \Gamma(s,1)=\gamma_1(s) & 0\le s\le 1 \\
>       \Gamma(0,t)=\Gamma(1,t) & 0\le t\le 1 \\
>    \end{cases}

I think, the last condition only means the curves $s\mapsto \Gamma(s,t)$ must be closed.

The problem is:

> Show that if we remove the condition "$\Gamma(0,t)=\Gamma(1,t)$" in the above definition, then the curves $\gamma_0(s)=e^{2\pi i s}$ and $\gamma_1(s)=1$ if $0\le s\le 1$ would be homotopic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Any hint to find this "homotopy"?

Another question. Why this is a different definition of what "homotopy" means in topology? In a arbitrary topological space, one cannot talk about closed rectifiable curves. But there, if the above statement is true, then the unit circle and a point are homotopic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, while in complex analysis they are not.

Comment: The condition is that the curve cannot be opened then closed to go through a point for example.